# Question regarding common class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have following two classes:

```
public class A : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
    {

        public virtual string X
        {
            get
            {
                object obj = ViewState["X"];
                if (obj != null) return (string)obj;
                return null;
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["X"] = value;
            }
        }


        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            X=2;
        }

    }
```

and

```
public class B : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox        {

        public virtual string X
        {
            get
            {
                object obj = ViewState["X"];
                if (obj != null) return (string)obj;
                return null;
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["X"] = value;
            }
        }


        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            X=2;
        }

    }
```

As you must be seeing the class A and B have exactly the same code , my question is how can I make a common class for it and use these two classes.

Comment: Not sure the best approach here, but your getting can be simplified to `return ViewState["X"] as string;`

Comment: Jon, that is great! . It can be written with single line. Thanks . Now as per my original quetsion I was thinking to make a common logic somewhere so that I can use it in my classes. I am going to use many classes with same code and property.

Comment: This could be solved with multiple inheritance, but since there isn't any in C#, I guess you'll have to add it every class you need to.

Comment: @SWeko, multiple inheritence is not the only way to approach this, there are a number of very simple patterns you could use, ie Decorator.

Comment: @Matt Can you give me example with reference to my code?

Comment: @Jon I don't like replacing that with `as` since `as` treats a wrong type as equivalent to `null`. I'd replace the code with `(string)ViewState["X"]` since the normal cast will work on null correctly, but throw if you made a typing mistake.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Agreed, I'd actually misread the original code, thinking it was performing an "is" test. Not sure why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement for inheritance is composition. 
Define a new class and insert invocations of it's methods in A and B. In this example it seems too complicated, but you will avoid code duplication if you decide to replace ViewState["X"]

```
class C { 
        public virtual string X
        {
            get
            {
                return ViewState["X"];
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["X"] = value;
            }
        }     
        public SetX()
        {
            X=2;
        }
}
```

Extension methods is a good alternative too.